# Parameter to change the order of reactions for an activity with stream?

Tags: getstream-io

For a certain activity id (postid) I have an API endpoint that will return the list of reactions (comments) for that activity. It appears to me that the way in which the reactions are returned from stream is that the newest is at the top? I want the newest at the bottom like how facebook is.

As far as what I've seen or tried I just see what the documentation has:
https://getstream.io/docs/python/#reactions_retrieve-reactions

I do see that it seems to support pagination which I also need so that's great.

```py
class ListCommentsForPost(ListAPIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, postid, *args, **kwargs):
        response = stream_client.reactions.filter(
            activity_id=postid,
            kind="comment",
        )
        serializer = CommentSerializerStream(response['results'], many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Ultimately, I just expect to be able to change the order of how reactions are returned chronologically. When stepping the code I do see it is indeed an OrderedDict so maybe the answer is to just try to manually reorder it? Should probably still be a query parameter though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reactions are returned in descending order (newest to oldest) by default or when using id_lt[e] and in ascending order (oldest to newest) when using id_gt[e].

You can retrieve reactions from oldest to newest  by providing a value to the `id_gt` paramter; for the first page, *any* value will do.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess when I read it it didn't register as being the order by date. Maybe putting a little more detail in the parameters section versus the text above would help it be more clear. But regardless thanks so much!